# Parse date with possible single-digit month/day/hour using java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, parsing, datetime, talend

On a project with Talend Open Studio (an Open Source code-generating ETL tool), I am getting errors parsing incoming date strings like "3/14/1967 0:00:00" (*note the single-digit month*).

Digging into [the](http://repository.georchestra.org/svn-georchestra/sdi/trunk/job/edigeo2shp_0.1/edigeo2shp/src/routines/system/ParserUtils.java) [code](http://repository.georchestra.org/svn-georchestra/sdi/trunk/job/edigeo2shp_0.1/edigeo2shp/src/routines/system/FastDateParser.java), I can see it is using [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). So the date pattern string I expect I need to use is **"d-M-yyyy H:mm:ss"**... but it keeps giving me errors like "Unparseable date: 3/14/1967 0:00:00".

I assume that SimpleDateFormat *can* deal with the single-or-double digit problem. **Do I need a different date pattern?** (Sure, I could do pre-processing to tweak the values before Java attempts to read the strings as Dates, but it shouldn't be necessary!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you *actually* need to use `d-M-yyyy` rather than `M/d/yyyy`? I can see why it would have a problem with "3/14/1967"... what date did you expect that to be? Note that not only have you got "d" and "M" the wrong way round, but you've also specified "-" instead of "/" as the separator.

Comment: Gosh, that's embarrassing! I should just give up now before I do something even more thoughtless. You are exactly right: I had swapped the month and day values, and had dashes instead of slashes. Sheesh.