# Best way to handle dates possible having single or double digits for month/days

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat

What's the best way to handle dates with days/months possibly having a single or double digits?

I have the following `DateFormat`:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
```

and the application I'm handling is doing well until one day it broke because it received a date like this:

```
2012-03-5 00:00:00.001 (Notice the single digit day).
```

I stumbled across this: [Parse date with possible single-digit month/day/hour using java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3936473/parse-date-with-possible-single-digit-month-day-hour-using-java-text-simpledatef) but it did not answer my question.

Do I really have to do some tweaking to the date string prior? Or is there any other neater way?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss.SSS?

Comment: your format error is because the input is `00:00:00:001` while your pattern is `HH:mm:ss.SSS`,

Comment: @Amit, yes i have tried yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss.SSS but it still won't work.

Comment: @Rangi, oh yes, just a typo. I'm very sorry. I have edited it now.

Comment: Can you show us the code you used for parsing date string ?

Comment: Hi @Rangi, it goes something like:

`foo.setValue(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-d HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2012-03-5 00:00:00.001"));`

Comment: What error you are getting ? this code works for me.

Comment: @Rangi, my fault. the error was somewhere else. isolated the code and yes, it works. really my fault. thank you guys for your great help.